# Cross product and right hand rule

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

Is there a simple proof that the cross product (defined as the usual determinant) always obeys the right hand rule?

Answer (score 2):

By the linearity and anticommutativity, it suffices to prove that $i\times j=k$.  $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}i&j&k\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right|=k$$

A similar computation  proves that $j\times k=i$ and $k\times i=j$.

Comment: I see that it works for the unit vectors i,j,k- but I don't understand how linearity and anticommutativity imply it must be true for all vectors.

Comment: The only reason you need the RHR is to determine $\pm$; the direction is specified as normal to the $u-v$ plane, and the length is $|u||v|\sin\theta$.